# Returning records in Delphi-Mocks

Tags: delphi, delphi-mocks

I would like to, using Delphi-Mocks, mock a class with a function returning a record. TValue and my record are reported as incompatible types. Is there any way I can do this with WillExecute or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Found out:

```
myMock.Setup.WillReturnDefault('function_name', TValue.From(rec_variable));
```